# Mockito mock calls actual implementation when not told to

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class which contains the following three methods:

```
void add(Service... objs)
void add(Collection<Service> objs)
void add(Stream<Service> objs)
```

As you might expect, these all support the adding of zero or more objects, which can be specified individually or as part of an array, a collection or a stream. The first two variants create a stream from their arguments, and pass them to the third variant which actually does the adding.

In testing an object that uses this class, I have created a Mockito mock object to represent an instance of this class, using Spring's @MockBean annotation. I can see in the debugger that the object under test contains the mock object, and that the call I am expecting (with a single argument of type Service) is being addressed to the mock. Because the method that should be called is the first variant (the varargs one), and I know that varargs parameters are a little tricky, I coded the test to check that the mock is called with the correct parameter as follows:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Service> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Service.class);
verify(theMock).add(captor.capture());
assertThat(captor.getAllValues()).containsExactly(expectedService);
```

However, when I run this code the assertion fails because the List returned by captor.getAllValues() contains not a Service, but a Stream: the failure message says:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting:
  <[java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@2cfe272f]>
to contain exactly (and in same order):
  <[com.xxx.data.Service@37c5]>
but some elements were not found:
  <[com.xxx.data.Service@37c5]>
and others were not expected:
  <[java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@2cfe272f]>
```

When I run the code in the debugger, I can see that the call from the object under test to `add(Service...)` invokes the real implementation; this invokes `add(Stream<Service>)` and it is that call which is intercepted by the mock. That explains why I am seeing the failure, but I don't understand why the mock is failing to intercept the original call, or what I can do to make it do so.

Answer (score 0):

Update your ArgumentCaptor to accept `Service[]`

```
ArgumentCaptor<Service[]> serviceCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Service[].class);
```

And assert

```
Service[] actualServices = serviceCaptor.getAllValues();
assertEquals(actualServices.length, 1);
assertEquals(actualServices[0], service);
```

And it's best practice to use **ErrorCollector** in **Junit** to assert more than one

assert and **SoftAssect** in **Testng** and call after your assertion **softAssert.assertAll()**

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help. The mock is still calling the actual implementation of the add(Service...) method, and the verify(theMock).add(captor.capture()) call throws a NullPointerException because it is calling the actual method with a null argument.

Comment: but this how you capture vararg

Comment: Absolutely, but that's not my problem. My problem is that the mock isn't intercepting the call to the varargs method, but is calling the real implementation of that method and intercepting the call from that method to another.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a workaround to the problem, but the actual problem still exists and I think it is probably a Mockito bug (raised as https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1929).

The workaround is to add this method to my test class. I've added a generic method because it is not just a call to the add() method that has the problem, but also a call to a similar overloaded remove() method that takes String arguments.

```
    private <T, V> void verifyCall(T mock, BiConsumer<T, V> call, 
                                     V expectedArg, Class<V> type)
    {
        ArgumentCaptor<V> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(type);
        call.accept(verify(mock), captor.capture());
        List<?> values = captor.getAllValues();
        try {
            assertThat(values.get(0)).isEqualTo(expectedArg);
        } catch (AssertionFailedError ex) {
            assertThat((Stream<V>) values.get(0)).containsExactly(expectedArg);
        }
    }
```

This should work whether the call intercepted by the mock was to the varargs variant of the method (as it should be) - in which case the assertion in the body of the try block will not throw an exception - or to the Stream variant (as it currently is) - in which case the assertion in the body will throw an exception and the assertion in the catch block will be executed.

Then, when I want to verify that my mock's add() method was called with the expected Service object, I do so with:

```
verifyCall(theMock, Datastore::add, expectedService, Service.class);
```

And similarly, for the remove() method:

```
verifyCall(theMock, Datastore::remove, expectedDeletedKey, String.class);
```

Very pleasingly, when I finally got this working the test failed because I had made a mistake in the method under test. Which made it all worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

D'oh. I failed to spot that the two varargs methods were declared as final. Removed this and it all works as expected.